# Change css for hover over text box

Tags: html, css

The original idea came from the following

http://freshdesignweb.com/demo/2012/09/css3-hover-effects/

It is a simple hover over image then text relevant to that image drops below it.

I want to modify the area in which the text displays to add rich snippet code, a buy it now button, and an add to cart button. I am having two issues 1) any img scr added between the li automatically appears in the image box and 2) anywhere you click on the image or box takes you to another page since it is an anchor.

the css

```
.our_menu{width:970px; margin:0 auto;}
ul,li{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none}
.menu .item{float:left;position:relative}
.menu .item a{background-color:#FFF;color:#000000;display:block;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;box-shadow:0 0 7px 0 #CCC;-moz-box-shadow:0 0 7px 0 #CCC;-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 7px 0 #CCC}
.menu .item a:hover{z-index:2;-webkit-transition:height .2s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:height .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:height .2s ease-in-out;-ms-transition:height .2s ease-in-out;transition:height .2s ease-in-out}
.menu .item a h3{border:0;font-family:"Times New Roman",sans-serif;font-size:17px;margin:0 0 .5em 0;padding:0;text-transform:uppercase;}
.menu .item a p{color:#432;font-size:16px;}
.our_menu .menu{float:left;margin:0 0 50px 0}
.our_menu .menu .item{background-position:9px -791px;height:170px;padding:0 0 0 7px;width:316px}
.our_menu .menu .item a{height:25px;padding:114px 0 0 14px;top:10px;width:295px;text-decoration:none;}
.our_menu .menu .item a:hover{height:550px;padding-top:179px}
.our_menu .menu .item a img{clip:rect(0px,283px,96px,0px);height:164px;position:absolute;top:14px;width:283px}
.our_menu .menu .item a:hover img{clip:auto}
@media only screen and (max-width: 967px) {
.our_menu{ width:660px;margin:0 auto;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
.our_menu{ width:330px;margin:0 auto;}
}
```

Original html

```
<div class="our_menu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="item">              
            <a href="#">                    
                <h3>Appetizers</h3>                    
                <p> Start a meal off right with your favorite from our menu of signature appetizers. Can't choose just one? You don't have to</p>                    
                <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" height="164" width="283">                
            </a>            
        </li>
```

The following is the rich snippet code I need to use to make the text in the box.

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <img itemprop="image" src="http://www.example.com/images/hello.jpg" />
    <h3 itemprop="name">Name of Product Here</h3>
    <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/index.html"></a>
<span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"><h3 itemprop="price" class="price">$2.00</h3></span>
<p>
    <span itemprop="description">Widget</span><br/>
    UPC: 1234567890
</p>
<span>
```

The following is what I had working up until I wanted to add the buy it now button and add to cart button.

```
<a class="paypal"><img src="images/cart.gif" alt=""></a><a class="paypal"><img src="images/buynow.gif" alt=""></a>


<div class="our_menu">
    <ul class="menu">
    <li class="item">   
        <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/">       
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <img itemprop="image" src="images/hello.jpg" height="164" width="283"/>
    <h3 itemprop="name">Product Name</h3>
<span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"><h3 itemprop="price" class="price">$2.00</h3></span>
<p>
<span itemprop="description">Widget</span><br/>
    UPC: 074804800012<br/>
</p>
</a>
</li>
```

I created a jsFiddle thanks for the suggestion.

http://jsfiddle.net/3CmGN/

In the fiddle when you hover over the image a box containing text drops down.  I want this effect as is. The issue I am having is I do not want the image as a anchor tag and want to add an "add to cart" and "buy it now" button under the UPC in the example.

Comment: Create a jsFiddle please, makes life easier.

Comment: @Ruddy I appreciate the suggestion of adding a jsFiddle...never thought to do so. jsFiddle has been added.

Comment: UPC means Universal Product Code...the number next to UPC: would represent the product code of the specific product.  I just added it because it can be used to search in Google.

Comment: Do you need to act like this http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/DPv8D/1/

Comment: Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/DPv8D/6/

Comment: @Gandalf...your almost there.  In your example....if you click on the image it takes you to a url...I do not want the image to be an anchor.  Also could the buttons come from a url like www.example.com/add-to-cart.jpg or something like that.  I really appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: The add to cart and buy it now would both be <a href with img scr

Comment: Consider editing the html to get rid of the markup with links.

Comment: @Gandalf - everything I have attempted has not worked. As soon as I start messing with the css or html this breaks which is the reason I posted the question for the css masters.